# Chrome extension: click on link after redirect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have Chrome extension, which catch click on any link and redirect to other page.
Now I want to fire click on first link on new page and I don`t know how.

This is my piece of code:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect}, function(callback){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: "var firstdiv = document.getElementsByClassName('r')[0]; var firstlink = firstdiv.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; firstlink.click();"});
    });
});
```

Of course there is some permissions in my `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
```

Comment: Gain the URL from the link and redirect the page. With jquery: href = $('a:eq(0)').attr('href');
window.location.replace(href);

Comment: Are you sure the updated tab has finished navigating when you try and executeScript?

Comment: @abraham: I`m not sure that tab has finished navigating, but the question is how to detect, that specific tab loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by use `onUpdated` listener and global variable, which contain tab ID:

```
var tab_ids = [];

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect}, function(tab){
        tab_ids.push(tab.id);
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeinfo, tab){
    var index_of_element = tab_ids.indexOf(tabId);
    if (index_of_element > -1){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            file: 'click.js'
        });
        tab_ids.splice(index_of_element, 1);
    }
});
```